# Does one make a shehecheyanu on "used" jewelry?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shehecheyanu, jewelry

If someone is going to be wearing a "used" piece of expensive jewelry for the first time (as in, it was previously worn by a different person as opposed to being new from the store), do they make a shehecheyanu on it?

Comment: related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84318/5275

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any item which upon acquiring would typically warrant the *berachah*, then even if the item was previously used/owned by another party (think: house) the Shulchan Aruch rules ([OC §233:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.223.3?with=all&lang=bi)) that the *berachah* is recited.

Comment: +1 Specifically, “They only said ‘new’ to exclude if he sold them and bought them back.”